# Can someone find out my other websites based on the IP address of one of my websites?

Tags: ip, websites

As far as I know, the IP address of any website is detectable by a simple `ping` test.

Say I host several websites on a given webhost with a single IP.
If someone finds out the IP of one of my websites, could this person find all other websites sharing the same IP and if so, how?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find all domains hosted on a single host?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22949/how-do-i-find-all-domains-hosted-on-a-single-host), [How to find out what websites are associated with an IP that has port 80 open?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/140271/how-to-find-out-what-websites-are-associated-with-an-ip-that-has-port-80-open).

Comment: *"the IP address of any website is detectable by a simple ping test."* - kind of but not really. Getting the IP address(es) for a host are done by DNS lookups, which ping does before it tries to send packets to the IP address it got from the DNS lookup. Note that a site might have multiple IPv4 and IPv6 addresses and ping shows you only one of these, so this is not the complete information.